# Adding people to my group in Facebook

Tags: facebook-groups

I have over 5k people who like my page. The group I created within the page only lets me invite one person at a time. When I click "invite people who like my page" the screen comes up but I'm not able to click on anything and no names appear, just an empty box where it appears names should be listed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to add people in Facebook group with script instead of adding them one by one manually. This method bypasses limit of 1000 members so now you can add 1000 plus members in your Facebook group.

[How to add 1000 members in Facebook group](https://hackingtryx.blogspot.com/2015/05/script-to-add-all-friends-in-group.html)

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, since it's your own blog your linking to, you need to state so explicitly in order to avoid having your post deleted as spam. See the [Help Center](/help/promotion) for more information.